# Xcode 7 Swift 2 - How can I initialize a view with a .SKS file?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I have looked everywhere for examples on how to initialize a view from a `.SKS` file. Every example I found seems to now be broken with the introduction of Swift 2 and Xcode 7. I am using Xcode 7 GM.

Could someone please provide an example of how to do this in the quickest way possible?

Edit* Please be aware of both the iOS version and Xcode version before you mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using sks file with SKScene subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212771/using-sks-file-with-skscene-subclass)

Comment: @cybermonkey Please look at versions before you mark as a duplicate question. Also, notice one is using Objective-C and this is Swift.

Comment: By 'view' do you mean `SKScene` or `SKScene` subclass? If so, would suggest you take a look at the default project that gets created, by Xcode, when you select the 'Game' template when creating a new project.

Comment: I guess how to I get a view controller to load a .sks file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied my code off of the SpriteKit sample project. I'm at work now, I can convert it to Swift this weekend if you need me to. Runs in Xcode 7, on iOS 9.1.

```
@implementation SKScene (Archiving)

+ (instancetype)unarchiveFromFile:(NSString *)file {
  /* Retrieve scene file path from the application bundle */
  NSString *nodePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file ofType:@"sks"];
  /* Unarchive the file to an SKScene object */
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:nodePath
                                        options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe
                                          error:nil];
  NSKeyedUnarchiver *arch = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
  [arch setClass:self forClassName:@"SKScene"];
  SKScene *scene = [arch decodeObjectForKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
  [arch finishDecoding];

  return scene;
}

@end

// ...

@implementation VTMillScene

+ (instancetype)loadMill {
  return [self unarchiveFromFile:@"mill"]; // loads "mill.sks"
}

@end
```