# How to control scenekit character movement with SkSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I just completed my scenekit game, in which i have a moving character which start moving with single tape gesture.I want it move when a button in pressed to so i create play/pause button in skscene class.How i make my character move only when i press play button?
As this image[image]
Here is my code

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let _node:SKNode = self.atPoint(location)
        if(_node.name == "Play Button"){
                        parentView?.startGame()

        }
            if self.pauseNode.contains(location) {
                if !self.isPaused {
                    self.pauseNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Pause Button")

                }
                else {
                    self.pauseNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Play Button")

                }

                self.isPaused = !self.isPaused



        }
    }
```

Function for moving character in LevelOneViewController viewDidLoad()

```
func move (){
    Character.idle()
    let startTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LevelOneViewController.handleStartTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(startTap)

    let stopTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LevelOneViewController.handleStopTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(stopTap)
    stopTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    }
    move()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an overlay `SKScene` with a `SKSpriteNode` representing your play button and add a gesture recognizer to your node which will then update your Character. You then set this controls scene as the overlay  of your `SCNView`.

Some sample pseudo-code, you need to fill in the details:

```
class GameControlsScene:SKScene {

  var character:Character
  var playButton:SKSpriteNode
  var playButtonGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer

  override init(character:Character) {
    self.character = character
    super.init()
  }

  func didMove(to:SKView) {
    // add an SKSpriteNode for the play button
    self.playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"playButton")
    self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(<<w>>, <<h>>) 
    self.playButtonGestureRecognizer = // add a UIGestureRecognizer with selector as handlePlayButtonTap 
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.playButtonGestureRecognizer)
  }

  // gesture recognizer to handle play button tap
  func handlePlayButtonTap() {
    //in here move your character    
  }
}
```

Now where you set up your `SCNView` set the overlay.

```
var controlScene:GameControlScene(<<character>>
scnView.overlaySKScene = controlScene
```

Note that you could also make a `SKScene` in Xcode (`.sks`) file and load it instead of making one programmatically, but the rest of the details of adding a  gesture recognizer, hooking it up to your character in the 3D scene and setting it as overlay are the same.

With the `.sks` file, [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212771/using-sks-file-with-skscene-subclass).